# Bind Play/Pause/Ended functions to HTML5 video using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, events, video, bind

I am trying to bind `play`/`pause` and `ended` events using jQuery but there is a problem:

When I right click on the video and select play or pause the icons change correctly. When I click the play button it changes to pause, but if I click the pause button to continue the video it doesn't change to play again.

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

Here is my code:

```
    var PlayVideo = function () {
            if ($('#video').attr('paused') == false) {
                $('#video').get(0).pause();

            } else {
                $('#video').get(0).play();

            }
        };

        $('#playbtn').click(PlayVideo);
        $('#video').click(PlayVideo);

        $('#video').bind('play', function () {
            $('.playbtn').addClass('pausebtn');
        });

        $('#video').bind('pause', function () {
            $('.playbtn').removeClass('pausebtn');

        });

        $('#video').bind('ended', function () {
            $('.playbtn').removeClass('pausebtn');

        });
```

CSS:

```
    .playbtn {
    display: block;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    background: url('../images/play.png') no-repeat;
    opacity: 0.7;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; /* Opera */
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.pausebtn {
    display: block;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    background: url('../images/pause.png') no-repeat;
    opacity: 0.7;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; /* Opera */
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

There is no `pause`-attribute for HTML5 video. Instead you should have a look at **[media events and properties](http://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html)**.

In your case that would mean:

```
if (!$('#video')[0].paused) {
   $('#video')[0].pause();
} else {
   $('#video')[0].play();
}
```

BTW: Since you are calling `$('#video')` pretty often it might be a good idea to store that in a variable - this way you don't have to call the jQuery-selector a gazillion times. Like:

```
$video = $('#video'); //from now on just use $video instead of $('#video')
```

**EDIT:** Regarding your comment it is hard to tell without seeing the controls (HTML & CSS) you are using but what you can do in any case is using the same handler for all the events that trigger the same behavior (and since the behavior is right on `pause` it should be on `ended` as well when bound to the same handler). Also, in the code you posted, you are using `removeClass` on ended (where it should probably be `addClass`). So this should work:

```
$('#video').bind('play ended', function () { //should trigger once on any play and ended event
    $('.playbtn').addClass('pausebtn'); //might also be $('#playbtn') ???
});

$('#video').bind('pause', function () { //should trigger once on every pause event
     $('.playbtn').removeClass('pausebtn'); //might also be $('#playbtn') ???
});
```

Another glitch i noticed is that you use `#playbtn` once and `.playbtn` another time. Make sure you are referring to the same items here when trying to do something with your Play-Button.

Comment: @m90-Thanks for mentioning it.Sorry it's a typo mistake.So how do I change the icon after the video ends.As after clicking the play btn it changes but again it is not toggling.

Comment: @DotNetter Apart from the fact that you could reduce the second class down to the `background:` line (the rest is the same) the CSS seems ok. Have you checked if a. the `ended` event really fires and b. if the new `background` rule doesn't get overwritten by some other style?

Comment: Everything works fine If I right click on video but the problem is with the buttton.It's not toggling after pausing the video.

Comment: @DotNetter Will the events fire? Will the additional class get applied? Please check on that.

Comment: Yes.It's getting fired as I'm not showing any errors with firebug.

Comment: @DotNetter, no errors doesn't mean that it actually does fire: You can do `$('#foo').bind('click',function(){alert('w00t');})` and it won't throw an error because the syntax is correct but if there's no `$('#foo')` on the page for example (or it never gets clicked) it will still never trigger the handler