# Checking for end of video on iPad

Tags: javascript, ipad, html5-video

I can't seem to listen for onended on a video on iPad(Safari)...I want to remove a class that I was able to add when the play button was pressed, but I can't seem to track down when the video ends (works well every where else including iphone, just need it for iPad/Safari)

link here: http://www.artandseek.net/meyerson/tour/

code snippet here

```
$(".playBtn").click(function(){
            var thisVideo = $(this).prevAll(".img-wrap").children(".togglePlay").get(0);


                thisVideo.onended = function(e) {
                        $(this).fadeOut().parent(".img-wrap").removeClass("playing");
                        $(this).parent().next("h2").fadeIn();
                        classie.remove( thisVideo, 'tabletActive');
                        }; ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the answer here:
[Bind Play/Pause/Ended functions to HTML5 video using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9874095/bind-play-pause-ended-functions-html5-video-using-jquery)

using this:`$(thisVideo).bind('ended', function () { 
                    console.log('working');
                });`